# Password protect a multiplayer game?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On the iOS version for a tablet is there a way to password protect the multiplayer game so that other people on the same wifi network can not access the world?

Answer (score 2):

**As mentioned in the previous answer, you need to disable local server multiplayer.** Here are the steps to do that.

If you want no one else to go into your current game:

1. Press the pause button on the right hand side of your IPhone, iPad or computer.
2. Press or click "Quit to Title".
3. Now press or click the options sign.
4. Then turn off the local server multiplayer.

Or when you are on the title screen:

1. Press or click play.
2. Next, press or click the pencil picture next to the game you want no one to go to.
3. Then again turn off local server multiplayer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is go to settings and turn off local server multiplayer. Then no one can get into your world and kill you or take your stuff.

Answer (score -1):

No, sorry there isn't. If someone else is trying to join your world, you just have to tell them to go away.

Comment: Telling them to go away wouldn't really help.